# How can I install ubuntu from the Gparted boot disk?

Tags: gparted

I currently have  2 boot disks, one for Gparted and another with a windows 7 that didn't work. I only have access to a os thorough the gparted disk, but how do I get Ubuntu on a flash drive with that ?

Comment: Yes, its the live cd. I assume I need to direct it to the iso of Ubuntu?  And if so, how do I do that?

Comment: Do you intend to use the `dd` tool or a safer tool, for example `dus`? With `dd` you change the current directory to where you have the iso file and point to it with if=ubuntu-file.iso (of course with the actual file name). With `dus` you can do it with the graphical user interface.

Comment: The tar bar option worked out best and made it super easy.

Comment: Congratulations! I'm glad your solved your problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your gparted  disk is a live CD (or DVD) with gparted according to this link:

[gparted.org/livecd.php](http://gparted.org/livecd.php)

It means that the basic linux tools should be available, for example **`dd`**, which can do the job for you.

`dd` is a very powerful tool, but also very dangerous. It does what you tell it to do without questions. So if you tell it to wipe your family pictures ... and it is a minor typing error away. You can use it, if you **know what you are doing**, and you **check and double-check**, that you will write to the correct target device, the flash drive.

You can identify the drives and find the flash drive with the following command lines,

```
df
sudo lsblk -f
sudo lsblk -m
```

Then you run the following command lines. Change the current directory to where you have the iso file, maybe 'Downloads'

```
cd
cd Downloads
```

Maybe in another drive. In that case you must mount the partition where you store the iso file, and change directory to where it is

```
sudo mount /dev/sdxn /mnt
cd /mnt/path-to-iso-file
```

where **x** is the drive letter, **n** is the partition number and 'path-to-iso-file' is the path to the iso file within that partition, so for example `/dev/sda1` and `/mnt/home/bcbro/Downloads`

Then you run the `dd` command line, where you should use the actual file name of the Ubuntu iso file (instead of 'ubuntu-file.iso')

```
sudo dd if=ubuntu-file.iso of=/dev/sdx bs=4096
```

where **x** is the device letter for the flash drive, so for example `/dev/sde`.

---

If you want to play safer, you can install **`dus`** into your live gparted system (yes, I know, it is only temporary, but anyway), and let it wrap a safety belt around `dd`. **In this case it is probably easiest to install `dus` via a tarball** according to the following link,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui/tarball](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui/tarball)

It should be enough to download `dus.tar.gz`, the minimal version. Follow the instructions at the link above. If the installer wants you to install some other programs, please do so. Otherwise there might be problems to run `dus`.

Now you are ready to use `dus` alias `mkusb-dus`, either from the command line, or via the menu, 'guidus'. See the [mkUSB-quick-start-manual-12.pdf](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=mkUSB-quick-start-manual-12.pdf)